# Python: compute floating point accuracy as a function of floating point value

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to reproduce the following plot from [wikipedia's page on the IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

[image]

Unfortunately, the wikipedia article doesn't specify how they produced this data, and it doesn't seem trivial to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly is plotted there, but `np.nextafter` seems to give fairly similar results:

```
>>> x = 10**np.linspace(-12, 12, 50)
>>> y = np.nextafter(x, 2*x) - x
```

and

```
>>> x = 10**np.linspace(-12, 12, 50, dtype=np.float32)
>>> y = np.nextafter(x, 2*x) - x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! nextafter seems exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, do you know why someone downvoted my question? I thought it was clear and pertinent...

Comment: @Fabzi I don't know. Maybe they felt you could have shown more of your own efforts to solve the problem but I'm just guessing.